# How to make fisheye lens for camera

Tags: camera

I recently started using blender 2.82. I'm able to tweak and modify the settings of shading and modeling for material. I'm thinking of animating a scene using the vision of fisheye lens, can anyone help me with the camera settings for this case.

Comment: Hi. Where *specifically* are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Cycles render engine allows to use a fisheye lense. Select the active camera and open the *Object Data Properties*. Set the *Type* to *Panoramic* and select either *Fisheye Equisolid* or *Fisheye Equidistant*, depending on the type of fisheye lense you would like to use.

[image: Camera properties]

Comment: If I select "Type = Panoramic" I don't get the "Panorama Type" menu.
Any idea?
Blender 3.3.1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTOi6.png

Comment: @ioVideoMaker You are not using Cycles as render engine. Hence, the afformentioned options don't appear. You can change the render engine in the *Render Properties* tab.